# Why does this code generate such a confusing error message?

Tags: swift

Using Xcode 10.2.1, I'm trying to compile some sample code to respond to another thread here on SO (where somebody is trying to mutate a collection while iterating through it, but that's another story...)

```
func foo(_ array: [String]) {
    for (index, item) in array { // <<-- Error on this line
        print("Item \(item)")
    }
}
```

Using either the default setting of Swift 5, or Swift 4.2, the above code generates an error on the for loop "Expression type '[String]' is ambiguous without more context". Why is that? I also tried making the function definition `func foo(_ array: Array<String>)` but that generates the almost identical error "Expression type 'Array' is ambiguous without more context".

I realized after a lot of head-scratching that I made a bone-headed mitake and forgot to put in a call to `enumerated()`: `for (index, item) in array.enumerated()`. Why is the error message so incredibly obtuse? Thinking about what's wrong with the expression I typed, I'm trying to iterate through a collection and map each entry into a tuple, so I should get a type mismatch error. How can the compiler think that the expression `[String]` is ambiguous?

I am often impressed with how off-the-mark the Swift compiler's error messages are, but this one seems especially bad.

Comment: Could it be that [String] conforms to `Sequence` but since you are using a tuple in the for loop the compiler expects the more specialized `EnumeratedSequence` protocol (that conforms to `Sequence`)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess. it's basically saying it can't infer a type for `(index, item)` because it looked at the type of `array` and found more than one candidate function to match. It can't narrow down the choices enough or maybe it's narrowed them down to none.

To go much further probably requires examining the type inference code and everything to do with `Array<String>`.

You could raise this as a bug at the Swift project because the message is a bit confusing. It should probably say something like "can't infer a type to match (index, item)".